# Merging two adjacency lists into a new list in the same index keeping the same length

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list (adjacency list) called `List_1` which I want to merge with another 2D list called `List_2` into a new list called `mergedList`, without increasing the length.

`List_1` has `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]`
`List_2` has `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

I want `mergedList` to be `[[a,b,1,2],[c,d,3,4],[e,f,5,6]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done as next:

```
List<List<String>> list1 = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("a"," b"),
    Arrays.asList("c", "d"),
    Arrays.asList("e", "f"),
    Arrays.asList("e", "f")
);
List<List<String>> list2 = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("1"," 2"),
    Arrays.asList("3", "4"),
    Arrays.asList("5", "6")
);
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i  = 0; i < list1.size() || i < list2.size(); i++) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (i < list1.size()) {
        list.addAll(list1.get(i));
    }
    if (i < list2.size()) {
        list.addAll(list2.get(i));
    }
    result.add(list);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[[a,  b, 1,  2], [c, d, 3, 4], [e, f, 5, 6], [e, f]]
```

**NB:** This even supports cases where the size of the lists is not the same.